# Pandas : Calculate difference between max and min over time period

Tags: python, pandas

I need to calculate the difference between max and min value over 1 second period, the data frame looks like this, epoch is in miliseconds.

| Column A | Epoch |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1373981385937 |
| 11 | 1373981386140 |
| 13 | 1373981386312 |
| 8 | 1373981386968 |
| 7 | 1373981387187 |
| 7 | 1373981387421 |

I have to create a new column **diff** that is the difference between min and max of `'column A'` in each 1-second intervals. Note that these intervals are all relative to the min value of `'Epoch'` (the first value, 1373981385937, in the example above). First I get the first 1 second interval starting from 1373981385937 add 1 second, get the values in that range, calculate the max min difference and set `diff` to that value for the entire range, keeping the original index.

The desired result is:

| Column A | Epoch | diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1373981385937 | 3 |
| 11 | 1373981386140 | 3 |
| 13 | 1373981386312 | 3 |
| 8 | 1373981386968 | 1 |
| 7 | 1373981387187 | 1 |
| 7 | 1373981387421 | 1 |

Below I show how I currently do it:

```
current_index = 0
list_indexes = []
list_values = []
interval = 1000 # ms
while current_index < series.shape[0]:
    left = series.loc[(series["Epoch"] >= series["Epoch"].iloc[current_index]) & (series["Epoch"] < series["Epoch"].iloc[current_index] + interval)]
    value = left["Column A"].max() - left["Column A"].min()
    list_indexes.extend(list(left.index.values))
    list_values.extend(np.full(left.shape[0], value))
    current_index += left.shape[0]
result = pds.Series(data = list_values, index = list_indexes, name = label, dtype=np.float64)
```

I get the expected result, but the performance is poor.

Is there a way I can do it faster/better?

Edit:

Thank you for the support, but i cannot seem to integrate the solution in my code partly because i have to take into the accont two more columns

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Epoch | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 10 | 15 | 1373973055796 | 5 |
| 25 | 10 | 10 | 1373973055828 | 5 |
| .. | .. | .. | ............. | . |
| 25 | 12 | 18 | 1373973092296 | 2 |
| 25 | 12 | 16 | 1373973092328 | 2 |
| .. | .. | .. | ............. | . |
| 26 | 10 | 15 | 1373973055875 | 4 |
| 26 | 10 | 11 | 1373973055906 | 4 |
| .. | .. | .. | ............. | . |
| 26 | 12 | 13 | 1373973092359 | 3 |
| 26 | 12 | 10 | 1373973092406 | 3 |
| .. | .. | .. | ............. | . |
| 27 | 10 | 23 | 1373973055953 | 6 |
| 27 | 10 | 17 | 1373973056000 | 6 |
| .. | .. | .. | ............. | . |
| 27 | 12 | 17 | 1373973092921 | 7 |
| 27 | 12 | 10 | 1373973092953 | 7 |

The way I do it now is:

```
 for each unique value in colum A
  for each unique value in colum B
   gb = df.groupby((df["Epoch"] - df["Epoch"].min()) // 1000)["Column C"]
   kwargs = {label : gb.transform(max) - gb.transform(min)}
   newdf = df.assign(**kwargs)
```

Sorry for the long edit.
Do you thing there is a better way ?

Comment: why do you get 1/1/1 for the last 3? shouldn't those group together?

Comment: @mozway: I just understood that the OP wants the 1-second intervals anchored at `Epoch.min()`.  @catalin_345323: I attempted to clarify the question and emphasize the origin of the 1-second intervals. Please revert if that isn't what you meant.

Comment: @Pierre ok, seems reasonable

Comment: Ok, I took a guess at what you are looking for in the edited question and added some material to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below processes 1 million rows in about 151 ms (on a generic Intel Xeon Platinum 8175M CPU).

Using your example:

```py
gb = df.groupby((df['Epoch'] - df['Epoch'].min()) // 1000)['Column A']
newdf = df.assign(diff=gb.transform(max) - gb.transform(min))

>>> newdf
   Column A          Epoch  diff
0        10  1373981385937     3
1        11  1373981386140     3
2        13  1373981386312     3
3         8  1373981386968     1
4         7  1373981387187     1
5         7  1373981387421     1
```

Quick inspection: none of the below is necessary for the solution above, but is just to convince ourselves that the result is correct. We assign `t` the actual datetime, and `delta_t` as the difference in seconds from `t.min()`:

```py
t = pd.to_datetime(df['Epoch'], unit='ms')
tmp = df.assign(
    t=t,
    delta_t=(t - t.min()).dt.total_seconds(),
    groupno=gb.ngroup(),
)
>>> tmp
   Column A          Epoch                       t  delta_t  groupno
0        10  1373981385937 2013-07-16 13:29:45.937    0.000        0
1        11  1373981386140 2013-07-16 13:29:46.140    0.203        0
2        13  1373981386312 2013-07-16 13:29:46.312    0.375        0
3         8  1373981386968 2013-07-16 13:29:46.968    1.031        1
4         7  1373981387187 2013-07-16 13:29:47.187    1.250        1
5         7  1373981387421 2013-07-16 13:29:47.421    1.484        1
```

#### Edit: use first, last instead of min, max

In response to a comment: "Is there a way to replace max/min transform function in something that returns the first and last value of the group?"

Yes:

```py
newdf = df.assign(diff=gb.transform('last') - gb.transform('first'))
>>> newdf
   Column A          Epoch  diff
0        10  1373981385937     3
1        11  1373981386140     3
2        13  1373981386312     3
3         8  1373981386968    -1
4         7  1373981387187    -1
5         7  1373981387421    -1
```

#### Speed

```py
n = 1_000_000
t0 = 1373981385937
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column A': np.random.randint(0, 100, n),
    'Epoch': np.random.randint(t0, t0 + 300 * n, n),
})

def f(df):
    gb = df.groupby((df['Epoch'] - df['Epoch'].min()) // 1000)['Column A']
    return df.assign(diff=gb.transform(max) - gb.transform(min))

%timeit f(df)
# 151 ms ± 1.87 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

#### Addendum: additional columns (modified question)

IIUC, you'd like to do the same calculation, but within each group of `[A, B]` values. The origin for the time second-intervals is still the global minimum of `Epoch`.

```py
def f(df):
    gb = df.groupby(
        ['Column A', 'Column B', (df['Epoch'] - df['Epoch'].min()) // 1000]
    )['Column C']
    return df.assign(diff=gb.transform(max) - gb.transform(min))
```

Example on the provided sample data with the additional two columns:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column A': [25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27],
    'Column B': [10, 10, 12, 12, 10, 10, 12, 12, 10, 10, 12, 12],
    'Column C': [15, 10, 18, 16, 15, 11, 13, 10, 23, 17, 17, 10],
    'Epoch': [
        1373973055796, 1373973055828, 1373973092296, 1373973092328,
        1373973055875, 1373973055906, 1373973092359, 1373973092406,
        1373973055953, 1373973056000, 1373973092921, 1373973092953],
})

>>> f(df)
    Column A  Column B  Column C          Epoch  diff
0         25        10        15  1373973055796     5
1         25        10        10  1373973055828     5
2         25        12        18  1373973092296     2
3         25        12        16  1373973092328     2
4         26        10        15  1373973055875     4
..       ...       ...       ...            ...   ...
7         26        12        10  1373973092406     3
8         27        10        23  1373973055953     6
9         27        10        17  1373973056000     6
10        27        12        17  1373973092921     7
11        27        12        10  1373973092953     7
```

#### Speed

```py
### Speed
n = 1_000_000
t0 = 1373981385937
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column A': np.random.randint(0, 10, n),
    'Column B': np.random.randint(0, 10, n),
    'Column C': np.random.randint(0, 10, n),
    'Epoch': np.random.randint(t0, t0 + 300 * n, n),
})

%timeit f(df)
# 538 ms ± 4.74 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thank you, I manage to process 4 milion entries in 700 ms and in my original code the same data took just a little under 4 minutes

Comment: Is there a way to replace max/min transform function in something that returns the first and last value of the group ? I need this for something similar but instead of the difference between max and min I need the difference between the last and first element. I tried with a function like this def get_last(df): return df.iloc[-1], but is very slow.

Comment: Yes. See 'edit' in the answer.